# Why I am getting double response in chrome inspect -> network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, react-dom, inspect

[This is what it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgBHY.jpg)

Here is my code, can you please help me to find what's wrong I am doing?
I tried different things but it did not work. Photos and codes all given.

```js
const ProductScreen = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    //const product = products.find((p) => p._id === id);

    const [product, setProduct] = useState({})

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchProducts = async () => {
          const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
    
          setProduct(data)
        }
    
        fetchProducts()
    }, [])
    
   // if(!product) return null;

   // return ( <div>{product.name}</div> );

   return (
    <>
     // I thing this part of the code is not responsible for the issue
    </>
   )

}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: Maybe because of strictmode, it runs the effect callback twice to see if its pure ..

Answer (score 0):

Using React 18's Strict mode in development mode will cause [all `useEffect`s to be called twice](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93), causing the issue you see here.

The fix is pretty simple: use a library meant for this task (like [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/)):

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import axios from "axios";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Example />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

function Example() {
  const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery(["repoData"], () =>
    axios
      .get("https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query")
      .then((res) => res.data)
  );

  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <strong> {data.subscribers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong>✨ {data.stargazers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong> {data.forks_count}</strong>
      <div>{isFetching ? "Updating..." : ""}</div>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(<App />);
```